# How to loop foreach in blade while using jquery in Laravel

Tags: html, jquery, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I have never tried jquery so I have no idea what I'm doing, unfortunately.

This is my blade:

```
<h3>Comments:</h3>
<ul class="list-unstyled activity-list">
    @foreach ($threads->comments()->where('parent', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get() as $comment)
        <li>
            <img src="{{ $comment->user->getAvatar() }}" alt="Avatar" class="img-circle pull-left avatar">
            <p><a href="{{ route('profile.view', $comment->user->id) }}"> 
                {{ $comment->user->user_name }}</a>: 
                <br>
                {{ $comment->content }}
                <span class="timestamp">{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
            </p>
            @if ($threads->lock == 0)
                <a id="btn-comment" style="padding-left:3.5em">reply</a>
                <br>
                <form action="{{ route('threads.comments.add') }}" id="comment"  method="POST" style="padding-left:3.5em; display:none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="thread_id" value="{{ $threads->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
                    <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Add reply...">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add Reply">
                </form>
                <br>
            @endif
            @foreach ($comment->childs as $child)
                <div style="padding-left:3.5em;">
                    <img src="{{ $child->user->getAvatar() }}" alt="Avatar" class="img-circle pull-left avatar">
                    <p><a href="{{ route('profile.view', $child->user->id) }}"> 
                        <span style="padding-left:1em;">{{ $child->user->user_name }}</a>: </span>
                        <br>
                        <span style="padding-left:1em;">{{ $child->content }}</span>
                        <span class="timestamp" style="padding-left:4.3em;">{{ $child->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Here's my custom script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-comment').click(function(){
        $('#comment').toggle('slide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

These lines specifically are the ones that I'm trying to run using the script above:

```
@if ($threads->lock == 0)
    <a id="btn-comment" style="padding-left:3.5em">reply</a>
    <br>
        <form action="{{ route('threads.comments.add') }}" id="comment"  method="POST" style="padding-left:3.5em; display:none;">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="thread_id" value="{{ $threads->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="{{ $comment->id }}">
            <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Add reply...">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add Reply">
        </form>
    <br>
@endif
```

Ask me if you need further detail

Comment: `id` attributes need to be unique in a document. You're using a loop, resulting in multiple `id="btn-comment"` and `id="comment"`. Use a class instead or make the `id`s unique

Comment: you have to specify a unique ID for your btn. or you can use the `class` selctor for that function

JS : ```$('.btn-comment')....```
Blade : ```<a class="btn-comment" ... ```

Comment: ah, I see... thank you for your answers.. using class did the job

Comment: uhm.. there's another problem now after using class. whenever I click on any reply button, every forms are shown. I only want the one that I clicked on